# PostgreSQL Server doesn't listen when trying to connect through pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, networking, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server through pgAdmin III, but every time it says that the server isn't listening. I've configured `postgresql.conf` on the remote machine to listen to all addresses (`listen_adresses='*'`) and to allow my machine IP access to the server in `pg_hba.conf`. I restarted the server after making these changes. I'm able to connect to it using Windows on several different machines, including the one I'm currently unable to connect with but using Void Linux I'm simply not able to. Is there anything else that might be blocking my connection? Web searches only mention adding my IP to `pg_hba.conf` and to set `listen_addresses` to `'*'`.

Comment: What error message are you getting, exactly?

Comment: @NieDzejkob pgAdmin III shows

**Server doesn't listen**

The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports could not connect to server: No route to host Is the server running on host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I tried to use ```psql``` to get a backup of a given database and it also showed me an error message similar to this one. It was basically the *Is the server running on host...* part.

Comment: @NieDzejkob If it helps in some way, ```netstat -atn``` on the server shows that it is listening on port 5432.

Comment: How are you running Windows and Void Linux on the same machine?  Did you reinstall OSes in between, or are you using some kind of VM?  If the latter, it is likely not configured properly.  Can you describe the setup?

Comment: @jjanes I have it dual booted. Where I work they don't have a DHCP configured, so the IP's are static. That said, when I was installing Void Linux alongside Windows I configured the static IP on both OSes to be the same. I made the changes necessary for me to access the remote server via pgAdmin III and 4 on Windows and it all went fine, and then when I tried doing the same on Void Linux it didn't work.

Comment: @JoãoPedro `No route to host` is error, when computer cannot find path, how to connect to postgresql server. Have you correct settings of IP in Void Linux (IP address, network mask, default gateway)? Can you `ping` to postgresql server?

Comment: @JanMarek I cannot. The settings should be the same as on Windows. Same IP, same gateway, same network mask and same DNS servers. Any clue as to why I can't find a route to the server?

Comment: @JoãoPedro Please, try check this settings ones more. You can eventually try connect postgresql server using it's IP adress instead of FQDN (but this is only workaround for non-functioning DNS). And what about firewall - you can try to stop it and try `ping` the postgresql server.

Comment: @JanMarek Unfortunately I don't have access to the firewall. The configuration is indeed correct. I'm guessing it is an issue with the firewall. I'll talk to whoever is responsible for it and I'll report back once I have the answer. Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: @JoãoPedro I ment firewall on client dual boot machine... What you get from `iptables -L -n` command?